# Django MiddlewareMixin replacement

Tags: django, pytest

We have this Middleware class and test in Django 3.2, How do we update the code for Django 4.2.1 as we get required parameter get_response missing

Middleware class

```
class CountryMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        country_code = helpers.get_country_from_querystring(request)
        if country_code:
            request.COUNTRY_CODE = country_code

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        """
        Shares config with the language cookie as they serve a similar purpose
        """

        if hasattr(request, 'COUNTRY_CODE'):
            response.set_cookie(
                key=constants.COUNTRY_COOKIE_NAME,
                value=request.COUNTRY_CODE,
                max_age=settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE,
                path=settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH,
                domain=settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN,
                secure=settings.COUNTRY_COOKIE_SECURE,
                httponly=True,
            )
        return response
```

Test

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('country_code,country_name', choices.COUNTRY_CHOICES)
def test_country_middleware_sets_country_cookie(
    client, rf, country_code, country_name
):
    settings.COUNTRY_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    request = rf.get('/', {'country': country_code})
    response = HttpResponse()
    request.session = client.session
    instance = middleware.CountryMiddleware()

    instance.process_request(request)
    instance.process_response(request, response)
    cookie = response.cookies['country']

    assert cookie.value == country_code
```

so I have re-written the Middleware class as follows which I think
is correct

```
class CountryMiddleware():

    def __init__(self, get_response):
         self.get_response = get_response

    def process_request(self, request):
        country_code = helpers.get_country_from_querystring(request)
        if country_code:
            request.COUNTRY_CODE = country_code

    def __call__(self, request):
        """
        Shares config with the language cookie as they serve a similar purpose
        """
        self.process_request(request)
        response = self.get_response(request)
        if hasattr(request, 'COUNTRY_CODE'):
            response.set_cookie(
                key=constants.COUNTRY_COOKIE_NAME,
                value=request.COUNTRY_CODE,
                max_age=settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE,
                path=settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH,
                domain=settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN,
                secure=settings.COUNTRY_COOKIE_SECURE,
                httponly=True,
            )
        return response
```

How do I rewrite my test now?